# Last In-First Out Stack in bash?

Tags: bash

Is it possible to do Last In-First Out Stack using shell scripting?
I am not expert in bash but I would like to learn
I can do it in c++ as follows

```
int main()  
{  
    stack<int> stack ;  
  
    stack_push(stack);  
    stack_peek(stack);  
    stack_search(stack, 2);  
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Reading your code, a lot of stuff is hidden, and I feel like is the "good" stuff (aka how to implement it in C++). Nevertheless, a quick search on Google on "LIFO Stack in bash script" pointed me to this [Github](https://gist.github.com/bmc/1323553) repo. Hope you'll find it interesting. You may also find this [tutorial](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-the-bash/1565923472/ch04s05.html) on the subject very interesting.

Comment: Not related to the actual question: I'm confused. What is `stack = stack_push(stack)` supposed to do? Do you push the stack onto itself? And if not, where is the data you push onto the stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement a stack easily using an array.

Note that bash is not object oriented, so there is no way to write `mystack.doSomething()` like you would in C++. Instead, you have to pass the stack name as a parameter to the function: `doSomething myStack`.
If you need only one stack, you can hardcode the stack name inside the functions, which makes things easier.

### One Global Stack

```
#! /bin/bash
stack=()
push() { stack+=("$@"); }
peek() { printf %s\\n "${stack[-1]}"; }
pop() { peek; unset 'stack[-1]'; }
```

Interactive example usage. `$` is the prompt:

```
$ push a b
$ push c
$ peek
c
$ pop
c
$ pop
b
$ pop
a
$ pop # stack is empty, results in error
-bash: unset: [-1]: bad array subscript
```

### Multiple Stacks

```
#! /bin/bash
push() { local -n "stack=$1"; shift; stack+=("$@"); }
peek() { local -n "stack=$1"; printf %s\\n "${stack[-1]}"; }
pop() { peek "$1"; unset "$1[-1]"; }
```

Interactive example usage. `$` is the prompt:

```
$ push stack1 a
$ push stack2 b
$ peek stack1
a
$ peek stack2
b
```

### Other Operations

Remember that the stacks are just regular arrays. Functions like `size` or `search` can be implemented by accessing the array directly. For instance, for the size of `stack` write `${#stack[@]}`.

### Alternative Approach: Multiple Stacks In One Single Associative Array

Up until now, each stack used its own array. You have to make sure to avoid name collisions with the rest of your script. Because the variable for each stack used the stack name (first argument after `push`/`peek`/`pop`) the stacks could only have names accepted by bash (for instance `stack1`, but not `stack 2`, `3rdStack`, `.`, or `""`). As an alternative, you can store all stacks in a single associative array (also known as map). However, you will loose the direct array access from before, so implementing additional methods might get more involved:

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -A stacks=()
size() { local j="${stacks[.$1]}"; printf %d\\n "${j/-*/0}"; }
lastindex() { local i="$(size "$1")"; echo "$((i - 1))"; }
push() { local j="$(size "$1")"; stacks["$j.$1"]="$2"; stacks[".$1"]="$((j+1))"; }
peek() { local i="$(lastindex "$1")"; printf %s\\n "${stacks[$i.$1]}"; }
pop() { local i="$(lastindex "$1")"; peek "$1"; unset "stacks[$i.$1]"; stacks[".$1"]="$i"; }
```

This is only a basic implementation. You can only push one element at a time, that is, you have to write `push stackname a; push stackname b` instead of `push stackname a b`. `peek` or `pop` on an empty stack do nothing but print an empty line.

Comment: Nice implementation ! the only problem is when calling script uses the same varibale name  `push stack a`

Comment: @Philippe Thanks. You can automatically change the variable name used for `myStack` to something like `specialPrefixThatWontBeUsedAnywhereElse_myStack` -- just write `specialPrefix...` in front of every `$1`. Alternatively, you could manage all stacks inside a single dynamic array which would even allow for non-identifier names like `.`, `3`, or `" "`, but at the end of the day you always need a reserved variable. Personally, I prefer *"variable name = stack name"* because direct access to the array variable may be useful.

Comment: Agreed, just wondering if there is any guaranteed way to avoid name clash in bash.

Comment: It is possible to avoid name clashes with already existing variables: `compgen -v` list all variables. Pick one that is not in the list, for instance `unusedName="$(tr \\0 a < /dev/null | head -c "$(compgen -v | wc -L)")a"`. **However**, it is impossible to pick a name that is guaranteed to be unused by the rest of the program *in the future* (that is, *after* the name was picked). As an alternative, you could use a null-delimited tmpfile, but even in ramdisk this would be slower because you would loose random access.

Comment: You cannot do `unusedName=...` becasue calling script may be tempted to do `push unusedName a`.

Comment: `unusedName="$(...` was just a general approach to generate an unused name and store it *inside* `unusedName`. The name `"unusedName"` itself can be in use already; this is not a problem as long as you define it as `local unusedName=...` or `declare unusedName=...` inside a function. But it is not appropriate here. The approach "*all stacks in a single associative array*" would be the way to go here.

Comment: What I mean is even you declare with `local&declare`, it can still clash with calling scripts' variables.

Comment: With `local` there is no clash, even if the name is the same. That is the purpose of local. Example: `a=1; f(){ local a=2;}; f; echo $a` prints `1`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212708/discussion-between-socowi-and-philippe).

Answer (score 2):

If using bashisms anyway, you may also use the references introduced with v4.2.
By passing the stack name as first parameter, you avoid the forementioned issues.
Also passing another variable name to hold the result avoids subshells/forks:

```
# True if elements $2...$n ave been added to array $1
push()  { declare -n stack=$1 && { shift; stack+=("$@"); } }

# Provide value of topmost stack element $1[n] in var $2
peek()  { declare -n stack=$1 && { declare -n elem=$2 && elem="${stack[-1]}"; } }

# Provide value of topmost stack element $1[n] in var $2 and remove element from stack
pop()   { declare -n stack=$1 && { declare -n elem=$2 && elem="${stack[-1]}"; unset 'stack[-1]'; } }
```

I'd add " `2>/dev/null`" to each line.

Test:

```
$ declare -a s=()
$ declare ch=''
$ push s a b && declare -p s
declare -a s=([0]="a" [1]="b")
$ push s c && declare -p s
declare -a s=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c")
$ peek s ch && echo $ch
c
$ ch=''
$ pop s ch && echo $ch
c
$ declare -p s
declare -a s=([0]="a" [1]="b")
$ pop s ch && echo $ch
b
$ declare -p s
declare -a s=([0]="a")
$ pop s ch && echo $ch
a
$ declare -p s
declare -a s=()
$ pop s ch && echo $ch
.bashrc:205: s: bad array subscript
.bashrc: line 205: unset: [-1]: bad array subscript
```

You can use `alias` if you only got one stack:

```
declare haystack=()
alias push='push haystack'
alias peek='peek haystack'
alias pop='pop haystack'
```